# How can I create public display of all Activities for Current Day + X weeks in Future (WordPress)?

Tags: wordpress, activity, calendar, html

We use 4.6.14 on WordPress. We're a radio station and we book guests for appearing on-air. Each guest is managed as a **Contact** and their appearances are recorded as a defined **Activity** (e.g., On-Air Appearance). We track each guest's appearance history by looking at **Activities** associated with his contact information. We also run reports for **all on-air appearances** (regardless of **Contact**) so we know ourselves what is on the schedule and what holes we have to fill.

We can do all of the above via CiviCRM internally (hooray)!

***How can we dynamically display the "All appearances" view on our public site so that listeners get a list of upcoming guests?*** CiviEvents has RSS, HTML and iCal feeds that yields something close to what we want, but our appearances seem to be more like Activities than Events -- unfortunately Activities have no built in feeds. Also, my research shows that there may be such views in Drupal-based CiviCRM, but we're heavily in WordPress as a standard.

***Can we write code to poll the Activity data to return what we want? Is there another approach?*** Or is this even possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at writing a custom WordPress plugin along the lines of the [CiviEvent Widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/civievent-widget/) plugin. Basically, you'll query the CiviCRM API to get activities (filtered appropriately to your needs) and then render them as a shortcode and/or widget.

So, yes, you can write custom code to do this, even as there is no built-in display for CiviCRM activities.